# Метод event.char() обозначения клавиш, tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, события, char

У меня имеется небольшой код для считывания нажатия клавиш:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sys.tem")

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

window_width = 500
window_height = 300
x = (screen_width // 2) - (window_width // 2)
y = (screen_height // 2) - (window_height // 2)
root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")

text = ""

def func1(event):
    global text
    text += event.char
    if event.char == "Клавиша":
        print(text)
        text = ""

root.bind("<KeyPress>",func1)

root.mainloop()
```

---

И по нажатии клавиши `Enter`/`End` должно выполняться это:

```
if event.char == "Клавиша":
            print(text)
            text = ""
```

Так вот, если я пишу туда `Enter` или `End`, то никакого результата нету.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие обозначения для этих клавиш, или где их можно найти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь получить специальную клавишу, такую ​​​​как Return, End и т. д., 
вы можете использовать `keysym`, который предоставит имя клавиши.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Sys.tem")

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

window_width = 500
window_height = 300
x = (screen_width // 2) - (window_width // 2)
y = (screen_height // 2) - (window_height // 2)
root.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")

text = ""

def func1(event):
    global text
    text += event.keysym if event.keysym != '??' else event.char    # !!!
    
#    if event.char == "Клавиша":
    if event.keysym == "Return" or \
        event.keysym == "Enter" or  \
        event.keysym == "End":
        
        print(text)
        text = ""

root.bind("<KeyPress>", func1)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @user583147 пожалуйста.

Comment: Подскажите еще, как называются другие клавиши? PgDn, PgUp, Insert, а то они не работают если их так пишу

Comment: @user583147   https://www.google.com/search?q=tkinter+event.keysym&oq=tkinter+event.keysym&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i19i22i30.7522j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8