# Обозначения клавиш tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, события

Мне дали хороший ответ - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1565679/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-event-char-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88-tkinter/1565685#1565685)

Но там написали только про клавиши End и Return(Enter), а мне нужны названия других клавиш по типу Insert, PgUp, PgDn, и т.д.
Можете написать как они будут обозначаться или через какой метод `event.?` их вызывать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проявите немного фантазии, вам фактически уже дали ответ в прошлой теме.

`print(event.keysym)` - добавьте эту строчку и нажимайте интересующею вас кнопку.

```
def func1(event):
    global text
    text += event.keysym if event.keysym != '??' else event.char    # !!!

    print(event.keysym) # Добавьте тут 

    if event.keysym == "Return" or \
        event.keysym == "Enter" or  \
        event.keysym == "Next" or  \
        event.keysym == "End":
        
        print(text)
        text = ""
```

И вот всё печатает:

> Insert

> Prior

> Next

Далее подставляйте полученные названия клавиш в свои условия.

---

Но как по мне, лучше привязывать к `keycode`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def my_key(event):
    print(event.keycode, event.keysym)
    if event.keycode == 13:
        print("Вау, вы нажали Enter!")

root.bind("<Key>", my_key)
    
root.mainloop()
```

[keys](https://narvell.nl/keys)

Comment: Благодарю! Немного недопонял в прошлый раз)